# Undo "Edit with Divi" and remove Divi styles

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, divi

Clicked "Edit with Divi" on a WordPress page that was using Gutenberg, and now Divi CSS ids/classes like `et-boc` and `et_builder_outer_content` are being added which is breaking styling. How can I remove these? Have tried rolling back via the WP revisions but it has no effect, these additional wrapping CSS selectors are still there.

When editing the page, the formatting all looks correct as the `et-` and `et_` wrappers are not being added.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up going into the db and manually having to change the `_et_pb_use_builder` in `wp_postmeta` to `off`